# CSS and JS get lost when I edit htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

I have this wird behaviour on my htaccess:
All the "front" links are working fine, but on the editar_post and editar_usuario, the ones that include the GET parameters, I lose all the CSS and JS files:

```
RewriteEngine On

######     Admin     #####

# Posts

RewriteRule ^listar_posts/?$ listar_posts.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^editar_post/?$ editar_post.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^editar_post/([0-9]+)/?$ editar_post.php?post_id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^nuevoPost/?$ nuevoPost.php [NC]

# Usuarios
RewriteRule ^listar_usuarios/?$ listar_usuarios.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^nuevo_usuario/?$ nuevo_usuario.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^editar_usuario/([0-9]+)/?$ editar_usuario.php?id_usuario=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^editar_usuario/?$ editar_usuario.php [NC]

# Login
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC]

#Front
RewriteRule ^front/?$ front/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^front/([0-9]+)/?$ front/post.php?post_id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^front/tecnologia?$ front/search.php?seccion=Tecnologia [NC]
RewriteRule ^front/marketing?$ front/search.php?seccion=Marketing [NC]
RewriteRule ^front/emprende?$ front/search.php?seccion=Emprende [NC]
RewriteRule ^front/tips?$ front/search.php?seccion=Tips [NC]
```

Can you please help me?

(also if I put the CSS and JS on absolute paths I lose everything no mather what)

Comment: Can you show us one of the files? Also add the working state of this if there was any? A sample URL is useful too.

Comment: check the browser console, are they been blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**htaccess is working but base href add meta**

```
<head>
 <base href="http://www.domain.com/" />
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest